# WCF REST 4.0 WebClient default endpoint set Timeout

Tags: wcf, rest, webclient

I am using WCF REST 4.0 Default endpoint configuration, on client I am using WebClient.
Is there anyway to to configure New time out value for WebClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already used a custom class found [here](http://w3ka.blogspot.fr/2009/12/how-to-fix-webclient-timeout-issue.html).

```
public class MyWebClient: WebClient
{
   //time in milliseconds
    private int timeout;
   public int Timeout
   {
           get {
               return timeout;
           }
           set {
               timeout = value;
           }
    }

    public MyWebClient()
    {
           this.timeout = 60000;
    }

     public MyWebClient(int timeout)
    {
           this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
     {
           var result = base.GetWebRequest(address);
           result.Timeout = this.timeout;
           return result;
    }
}
```

The general idea is to override the timeout of the inner WebRequest. Great !